# How delete a user session with the element api?

Tags: plugin-elementapi, login

I need a function to logout a craft user and delete the session of that user. This must take place in the [element API plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) as an endpoint. Something like this:

```
function userLogout(){
    if (craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn()){
        // if user loggedin
        // how to logout?
    }
}

'api/logout' => array(
    'elementType' => 'User',
    'criteria' => ['id' => craft()->userSession->user->id, 'limit' => 1 ],
    'paginate' => false,
    'transformer' => function(\Craft\UserModel $user) {
        userLogout();
    }
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can end a user's session with the `craft()->userSession->logout()`, method, which the `UserSessionService` class [inherits from the `CWebUser` class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#logout-detail).

So, your `userLogout` function would look like this:

```
function userLogout(){
    if (craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn()){
        craft()->userSession->logout(false);
    }
}
```

### Additional information

Passing `false` to the `logout` method tells Yii not to "destroy" the session, and mimics the call in Craft's [`UsersController::logout` method](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionLogout-detail).

According to [the Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#destroy-detail), `destroy` "frees all session variables and destroys all data registered to a session." I'm unclear why Craft chooses not to destroy the session.

The `UsersController::logout` method also includes a few cleanup tasks, but those seem to be duplicates of the tasks performed in the [`UserSessionService::afterLogout`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionLogout-detail) method.

The `afterLogout` method is called from the `craft()->userSession->logout()` method, so you shouldn't have to worry about this manual cleanup.